# How to get more detailed error message - SQL operand type clash

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a simple union of tables, e.g.

```
SELECT foo, bar, ... FROM dbo.a 
UNION ALL 
SELECT foo, bar, ... FROM dbo.b
```

But it results in an error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 45
>
> Operand type clash: float is incompatible with date

Both of these tables have the same columns.

Other than using trial and error, is there a way to debug or examine the code so I know which column(s) are causing this error?

Comment: Does it matter? You will need to put them in the same order if you want results right?

Comment: I suppose you could compare the ordinal position of the columns (e.g. comparing them in information_schema.columns) but realistically this is why you explicitly name columns instead of using *

Comment: In any sort of "real life" situation/environment you don't want to use "*" anyhow because it's not dependable.  It's best to explicitly list the columns to ensure your code isn't broken by someone introducing a field in one and not the other at some point.  So, instead of looking for a way around this, I'd encourage you to focus on considering a different development approach.

Comment: @Gerik, Thanks, but explicitly naming columns doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Please see my edited question. 

Even when columns are explicitly named, it's not telling me which column is causing the issue

Comment: remove 1 column at a time and run the query, this way you can see which column is causing the error.

Comment: Hiya @N4v, I'm not sure if you've said which db you're using but you can provide the output of your table definitions?  For mysql this means running "describe <table-name>" for each table.  You might have the table names the same, but it sounds like the fields themselves are different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the column metadata for both tables based on column name and look for differences in the data types.

```
SELECT  a.COLUMN_NAME, a.DATA_TYPE, b.DATA_TYPE
  FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS a
  JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS b
    ON a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME
  WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = 'a'
        AND b.TABLE_NAME = 'b'
        AND a.DATA_TYPE <> b.DATA_TYPE
```

Your mismatched column should be listed in the result.  Any other results would also be worth a look as well.

Comment: Ah, nice solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

My experience with SQL Server is that when you create a UNION query, it decides on the data types of the output columns based on what's in the first query. Maybe all of the columns in dbo.a and dbo.b have the same names, but it seems like one pair of them have different datatypes - in dbo.a it will be some kind of DATE datatype, and in dbo.b it will be some kind of INT datatype.  So go look at the datatypes for dbo.a - any that are DATE, go see what the matching column on dbo.b is.

Once you determine which columns are mismatched, you can figure out how to proceed - remove that column pair from the query, or CAST the date column from dbo.a into an different datatype, or CAST the int column from dbo.b into a DATE, or whatever is analytical appropriate once you identify the problem.